# Draw the space between two lines for anomalies

Tags: r, ggplot2, anomaly-detection, geom-ribbon

Hi I want to draw the space between two lines with red and blue( representing the anomalies), but I don't succeed to make it. Only blue anomaly is drawn.
Here is my code :

```
library(RCurl)
t <- getURL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vladamihaesei/weather_covid/master/Tab/UVanomaly.csv")## if can not download it, try manually 
t <- read.csv(text =t)
head(t)
ggplot(t, aes(x=data, y=uv1920)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = uv1920)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = uv01_19)) +
  geom_ribbon(data=subset(t, uv1920 <= uv01_19), 
              aes(ymin=uv1920,ymax=uv01_19), fill="blue") +
  #scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits=c(0,20)) +
  #scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits=c(0,5)) + 
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "2 weeks", date_labels = "%d%b")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("red","blue"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One approach to get the space between the lines filled may look like so.

The basic idea is to split the data in `period`s which can be mapped on the `group` aes.

Unfortunately this is not a perfect solution. As you can see we get gaps at the intersection points. I've done something similar lately with a lot of manual work to fill the gaps but far less intersection points. Maybe someone else has a more general and feasible solution to tackle this issue.

```r
t <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vladamihaesei/weather_covid/master/Tab/UVanomaly.csv")

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

t1 <- t %>% 
  mutate(date = as.Date(data1),
         diff = uv1920 <= uv01_19,
         period = cumsum(diff != lag(diff, default = TRUE)))
t1 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=date)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = uv1920)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = uv01_19)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin =uv1920, ymax=uv01_19, group = period, fill = diff)) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "2 weeks", date_labels = "%d%b")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("red","blue"))
```

[image]